# Spring Batch vs Tivoli?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

I was reading about Spring Batch and I read the below:

> Spring Batch is not a scheduling framework. There are many good
> enterprise schedulers (such as Quartz, Tivoli, Control-M, etc.)
> available in both the commercial and open source spaces. It is
> intended to work in conjunction with a scheduler, not replace a
> scheduler.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html#springBatchBackground

So what is the difference between **Spring Batch** and **Tivoli**?

Comment: 1 is a scheduler, the other is not.

Comment: Please more details, if Spring Batch is not scheduler so what is it?

Comment: It is a framework to model and execute batch processes.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch is mainly designed to provide a runtime for java batch workload.

IBM Workload Scheduler (Tivoli) / HCL Workload Automation, like other schedulers, doesn't run the workload directly, but is used to triggers any kind of workload (jobs), including Spring Batch, on on-prem or hybrid and multi cloud environments, including Kubernetes.

It can trigger jobs based on calendar, time, considering free/working day, complex runcycles (e.g. 3 working days before the end of each month).

In addition it can trigger workload based on dependencies on other jobs, so that they can start as soon as the previous job (running on any other system) has completed successfully, or run jobs only if predecessor has completed with a specific RC or result. Or you can use logic resources and limits to control how many jobs using the same machine or resource can run at the same time.

It can be also used to trigger workload based on events, e.g. when a new file is uploaded.

In recent releases IBM Workload Scheduler / HCL Workload Automation also added built-in capabilities to transfer files.

IBM Workload Scheduler / HCL Workload Automation is also key to have a centralized monitoring and recovery of failures, to centralize security granting access to different teams only on their jobs, to have a centralized governance (e.g. auditing any change and recovery on jobs).
It's also able to forecast the job durations and when every job will run, and generate alerts if they are running too long or if based on predecessors they are expected to miss their deadline.